# virtual methods inheritance class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have got:

```
class A
{
   virtual void get();
}

class B: public A
{
   void get();
}

class C: public B
{
   void get();
}
```

and

```
int main()
{
   B     *i;

   i = new C();
   i.get();
   return (0);
}
```

if A::get() is virtual:

> i.get() calls C::get()

if A::get() is not virtual:

> i.get() calls B::get()

My question is:

Why do I not need to put virtual on B::get() to use C::get() with B.get()?

Comment: That's not real code. `virtual get();`

Comment: It should be something like virtual **int** get() or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods that override virtual methods from the base class will be implicitly virtual, too - that holds for the entire ihneritance chain.

```
struct A {
    virtual int f(int);
};

struct B : A {
    int f(int); // overrides A::f, implicitly virtual
    void g(float);
};

struct C : B {
    int f(int); // overrides B::f, implicitly virtual
    int f(char);  // doesn't override anything, not virtual
    void g(float); // doesn't override and isn't virtual,
                   // because B::g is not virtual either.
                   // It hides B::g instead.
};
```

Comment: The right way should be to explicitly put virtual in B and C then ?

Comment: @nsvir - it's good practice to mark them as virtual, too. C++11 also has the `override` keyword (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), which is a better way to mark the methods, if your compiler supports it.

Answer (score 1):

When a *member function* is declared `virtual` in a base class, it will be `virtual` for all child classes as well. The fact that you can omit the `virtual` keyword in the child classes does not imply it is not virtual.

Your assumption on the code you proposed, that follows:

```
int main()
{
   B* i;
   i = new C();
   i.get();
   return (0);
}
```

are misguided by the fact that the above code [won't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/899409cb2050579e) (even if you added the semicolons at the end of each class declaration/definition).

When you are dealing with pointers and you want to call a member function you can either dereference the pointer and use the `.` operator:

```
(*ptr).function();
```

or use the `->` operator:

```
ptr->function();
```

Your code does neither of them. But assuming what you actually meant was:

```
int main()
{
   B* i = new C();
   i->get();
}
```

you assumptions turns out to be right:

- if `A::get` is virtual, in `i->get`, `C::get` will be called
- otherwise `B::get` will be called.

> Why do I not need to put virtual on `B::get()` to use `C::get()` with `B.get()`?

You don't. The `void get()` member function is virtual from the base class, all the way to the `C` class. You don't need to repeat the `virtual` keywords, but I'd actually recommend it.